# Config Bootstrap Options

Tags: bootstrap, config

Which config bootstrap options are available for ExpressionEngine? Which one works best in a multi server environment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can recommend [Focus Lab's EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). It's easy to set up and easy to add options to as needed and it is perfect for multi server environments.

I usually don't bother with the multi server set up, and am just building the site on a subdomain and then just transferring to the live domain. But even in this basic case, the master config makes going live quicker and easier.

Answer (score 12):

Solutions mentioned  in the thread are all nice, but I think you learn a lot by creating your own config bootstrap. To that end, I found the following resources can help a great deal:

- [DRY applied to EE2 config](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/apply-the-dry-principle-to-build-websites-with-expressionengine-2/)
- [Three](http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/4/6/getting-to-know-expressionengine-2s-config-file.html) [in-depth](http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/4/11/getting-to-know-expressionengine-2s-config-file-part-2.html) [articles](http://jamieonsoftware.com/journal/2011/11/5/getting-to-know-expressionengine-2s-config-file-part-3.html) by Jamie Rumbelow on the EE config file
- [Hidden Config variables in EE2](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html)

Armed with those, it is easy to create bootstrap config files that will suit your needs.

Comment: I started with the NetTuts config file and have modified it to suit my needs over time. It's simple and doesn't try to do things I don't need. I also learned a lot more about hidden config variables this way.

Comment: I agree whole heartedly. It's the same as bootstrapping a site. Rather than pick Foundation or Twitter BS, extrapolate the parts you need and roll your own.

Answer (score 6):

The [NSM Bootstrap](http://ee-garage.com/nsm-config-bootstrap) technique has never let us down in multi-server environments.

Comment: That's the one I use.

Answer (score 6):

Many options are available as stated in other posts.

To add to that here is the [default config.php & database.php file templates for ExpressionEngine](https://bitbucket.org/webunder/ee2_config_template) we use.

Answer (score 4):

I built my own config file, because I had a setup that most of the prebuilt configs didn't have... My normal setup is, Local, Staging (Located on subdirectory, inside a folder) and then Production.

A lot of hooks were added for NSM .htaccess, CE Image, CE Tweet etc...

Just pushed the latest version of it to my Github.

https://github.com/madebymayo/ExpressionEngine-Environment-Config

Answer (score 4):

I'll second tidy's vote for the Focus Labs EE Master config. We are using it in a multi server deployment set up and it's awesome. Saves lots of time and I no longer worry about code deploying out with the wrong environment configs.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed with building your own. I built my own then modified FL's EE Master Config to suit my needs. Super flexible and it is really nice having a plug-and-play EECMS install ready to be loaded on to any server.

If you are using multiple environments then use something like Deeploy Helper to get URL's/Paths stored in the DB updated when you migrate http://www.hopstudios.com/software/deeploy_helper

Answer (score 3):

Focus Lab's Master Config also supports MSM ([with the aid of this gist](https://gist.github.com/d27570a3e52bdf656f54)).