# setting 'site_name' in config doesn't seem to work

Tags: config

Having read through this discussion [Config Bootstrap Options](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/450/config-bootstrap-options), and settled on using the method described on nettuts [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/apply-the-dry-principle-to-build-websites-with-expressionengine-2/), I've got myself a base build for EE with all my usual addons etc. That's all working very nicely, with one annoying exception.

Setting `site_name` in config seems to have no effect what so ever!

```
$config['site_name'] = "Base ExpressionEngine Install";
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong, or does this just not work? I've tried clearing the cache via the CP, but that made no difference.

These are just stand-alone sites, not MSM.

Here is the rest of my config file for reference:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('EXT'))
{
exit('Invalid file request');
}

/**
* THIS FILE WILL NEED PERMISSIONS SET TO 400 OR SIMILAR SO EE DOESN'T OVERWRITE IT.
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ExpressionEngine Config Items
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following items are for use with ExpressionEngine.
|
*/

/* Universal Variables */

$config['app_version'] = "253";
$config['license_number'] = "0000-0000-0000-0000";
$config['debug'] = "1";
$config['install_lock'] = "";
$config['system_folder'] = "sys";
$config['doc_url'] = "http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/";
$config['is_system_on'] = "y";
$config['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$config['site_name'] = "Base ExpressionEngine Install";
$config['allow_extensions'] = "y";

/* General
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['site_index'] = "";
$config['site_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['server_path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$config['cp_url'] = $config['site_url']."/admin.php";

/* Dynamic database connection settings
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/

switch ( $config['site_url'] ) { 
// local
case 'http://dev.example.com' :
    $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "localhost";
    $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "admin";
    $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "password";
    $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "dev-db";
  break;

// staging
case 'http://staging.example.com' :
    $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "mysql.exampleserver.com";
    $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "admin";
    $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "password";
    $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "staging-db";
break;

// live
default :
    $db['expressionengine']['hostname'] = "mysql.exampleserver.com";
    $db['expressionengine']['username'] = "admin";
    $db['expressionengine']['password'] = "password";
    $db['expressionengine']['database'] = "live-db";
break;

}

/* Universal database connection settings
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$active_group = 'expressionengine';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['expressionengine']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['expressionengine']['dbprefix'] = "exp_";
$db['expressionengine']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['swap_pre'] = "exp_";
$db['expressionengine']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['autoinit'] = FALSE;
$db['expressionengine']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['expressionengine']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['expressionengine']['cachedir'] = $config['server_path'].$config['system_folder']."/expressionengine/cache/db_cache/";

/* Member directory paths and urls
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['avatar_url'] = $config['site_url']."/uploads/system/avatars/";
$config['avatar_path'] = $config['server_path']."/uploads/system/avatars/";
$config['photo_url'] = $config['site_url']."/uploads/system/member_photos/";
$config['photo_path'] = $config['server_path']."/uploads/system/member_photos/";
$config['sig_img_url'] = $config['site_url']."/uploads/system/signature_attachments/";
$config['sig_img_path'] = $config['server_path']."/uploads/system/signature_attachments/";
$config['prv_msg_upload_path'] = $config['server_path']."/uploads/system/pm_attachments/";

/* Misc directory paths and urls
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['theme_folder_url'] = $config['site_url']."/assets/themes/";
$config['theme_folder_path'] = $config['server_path']."/assets/themes/";

/* Templates Preferences
-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
$config['save_tmpl_files'] = "y";
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = $config['server_path']."/assets/templates/";
$config['site_404'] = "404/index";
$config['strict_urls'] = "n";

// END EE config items

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| CodeIgniter Config Items
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The following items are for use with CodeIgniter.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = $config['site_url']."/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";
$config['url_suffix'] = "";
$config['language'] = "english";
$config['charset'] = "UTF-8";
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;
$config['subclass_prefix'] = "EE_";
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = "a-z 0-9~%.:_\-";
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['directory_trigger'] = "D";
$config['controller_trigger'] = "C";
$config['function_trigger'] = "M";
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
$config['log_path'] = "";
$config['log_date_format'] = "Y-m-d H:i:s";
$config['cache_path'] = "";
$config['encryption_key'] = "";
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;
$config['time_reference'] = "local";
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = TRUE;
$config['proxy_ips'] = "";


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./system/expressionengine/config/config.php */
```

Comment: I don't know, I seem to remember this being a bug though, I will have to double check that to be the case as for some reason I remember it being with $config['site_label'] vs $config['site_name'] being the problem

Comment: Thanks Natetronn. Looks like GDMac has found the bug on  EE bug tracker for us :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be able to actually use the "site_name" and for it to work,
you need to hack the core
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/15461/#8283

or install an extension i developed for this.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/override_site_name

**edit** Instead of in the `config.php` file,
You can override site_name in the main index.php
`$assign_to_config['site_name'] ='Name'`

Comment: Thanks GDmac, looks like it's a known issue. Many thanks for the workarounds. Hopefully it might get fixed soon.