# Alternatives to NSM Site Generator?

Tags: add-on, deployment

I want to create a base configuration of EE that have certain channels, templates, addons, etc. -- and then deploy that over and over again. It seems like NSM Site Generator was the solution I needed, but it's in alpha, doesn't work with the latest version of EE, and not being actively developed (due to time constraints, per the developer).

Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just have a local dev environment using MAMP. I have a couple of base setups that I use. One with structure and one without and then my most standard addons that end up on almost every site like wygwam, switchee, stash etc. I keep these up to date on my local machine. When I want to start a new site its simply a matter of uploading the files to the web server. Copy across the database. Make a few configuration file changes and purchase an EE license and any applicable addon licenses and I am good to go. I am sure there are probably fancier more automated ways but this has always worked well for me.

Comment: Can you just copy over the database? Aren't there environment specific entries in the database that might make that approach fail?

Comment: I have never had a problem with that. There should be nothing in the database that has anything to do with the server environment. You want to change your /system/expressionengine/config/database.php file and possibly the config.php file when you move over the files. When you first login to the new site you will have to go through admin > general configuration and change the path settings as well as go through file upload preferences and change path settings and membership preferences too (i know its a PITA like I said there may be a more automated way).

Comment: Or you can use multi-environment config file (config overrides) to mitigate that issue. [Focus Lab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) is a popular approach. Also see [Config Bootstrap Options](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/450/22)