# deploying version 2.8

Tags: 2.8, deployment

As deploy helper is currently not supported on the latest version of expression engine can anyone recommend a decent alternative.

I came across this one, but it hasn't been updated in 6 months so I'm a little unsure if it's supported.
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/reelocate

Can I just do a find and replace in my mysql file? In a code editor? with an owl!

Cheers
Dave

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find switching to a multi-environment config file a more convenient alternative than using an add-on for updating paths after migration (eg dev to staging to production). The really nice thing about using config overrides this way is that there is usually zero configuration update needed when migrating.

One excellent, widely used and well-documented method is the [Focus Lab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config). Some other approaches are here in the EE Answers Stack Exchange post, [Config Bootstrap Options.](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/450/config-bootstrap-options)

You can also roll your own. Here are some helpful resources:

- [Multi-server Setup for EE 2](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-server-setup-for-ee-2)
- [Apply the DRY Principle to Build Websites With ExpressionEngine 2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/apply-the-dry-principle-to-build-websites-with-expressionengine-2--net-16848)
- [ExpressionEngine Configuration Variables (on Devot:ee)](http://devot-ee.com/ee-config-vars)
- [System Configuration Overrides (official docs)](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html)