# Setting up Git version control for a multi-environment workflow

Tags: focus-lab-master-config, git, workflow

I've got a live EE site and I need to put it under version control using multi-environment config settings.

My goal is to set a git workflow, so these would be the steps I believe are right for my needs: I just want to track templates, css, js and html changes.

STEPS:

1 - Using SFTP, download all production files to my local machine

2 - Dump a production SQL database.

3 - Then, on my local machine I make a fresh install of ExpressionEngine, using the same EE version as the live site.

4 - I put in place Focuslab config settings for local, staging and production.

5 - Add all production files to my local web root

6 - Import the dumped database

7 - Site is ready in local.

8 - Then, I add .gitgnore to ignore all upload images, media and cache.

9 - Git init

10 - My local site is ready.

11 - Then, I go to the staging server to create the staging site just by repeating  3, 4, 5 and 6 steps.

12 - Now, on local I will be able to test addons, for instance, and git push them to the staging site.

TWO QUESTIONS:

- On the production server I should modify config to use the Focuslab config settings?
- I guess, even though I'm not tracking uploaded content, I still have to synchronise production database with the local db, every time I make a change in local, like using a new addon?

Any ideas?

Comment: Before you begin any of this, do you have ssh access to your production (live site) server?

Comment: Yes, I do have ssh access to the production server.

Comment: Details added below. If you need steps for setting up a staging site too, I can add that later.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*I'll add to this as needed.*

Since you have ssh access to the server, start there.

**1)** Connect via ssh to the production server via Terminal (or iTerm app). `cd` to the root of your site (or the directory where you want to track changes).

---

**2)** Type the following:

`git config --global user.name "SITE NAME Prod Server"`
`git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com` use company or your email
`git init`
`git add .`
`git commit -am "initial commit, all files added"`

Now you have your site files tracked on your production server. For good practice (and ease), next you'll set up a central repo "hub". (See comments below for some thoughts on this.)

---

**3)** Sign up for Bitbucket (or pay for GitHub). Note: you can't put an EE site on a public repo.

---

**4)** Back on your production ssh connection, create an ssh public/private key pair.

Type 
`cd ~`
`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"`
Follow step 2 of GitHub's helpful instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#step-2-generate-a-new-ssh-key

---

**5)** Copy your key to your computer's clipboard from Terminal

Type
`pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

---

**6)** Add this key to Bitbucket so you can push to their server. [See how: step 6 here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git#SetupSSHforGit-#installpublickeyStep6.InstallthepublickeyonyourBitbucketaccount).

---

**7)** Create an empty repo on Bitbucket.

---

**8)** Now let's connect your server's repo to your new Bitbucket repo. Back in Terminal, type:
`cd /path/to/your/project`
`git status` - make sure you are actually in your repo
`git remote add origin https://USERNAME@bitbucket.org/USERNAME/MY-REPO.git` - Use your Bitbucket username and repo short name.
You should see it processing to send the files. After it's done, check Bitbucket and make sure your source files are there now.

---

**9)** Pull the repo to your local machine (or staging/dev server). Grab the ssh clone command from Bitbucket for your repo (it will be something like `git clone git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/MY-REPO.git`).
Using terminal, go to your local machine's (or staging/dev server's) directory where you want to add the site files. Note that this will create a root folder, so I usually name my repo folder 'public_html`.

Type your clone command:
`git clone git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/MY-REPO.git public_html`

---

**10)** To be able push to Bitbucket from your local machine (or staging/dev server), follow steps 4-6 for your local machine (or staging/dev server).

From here, you are connected from local to production.

---

**11)** Add a .gitignore file to your local root directory (in this example, /public_html/.gitignore) to ignore all upload images, media and cache (and whatever else you don't want to track). Don't ignore the .gitignore file because you want it added to your other environments too.
[Example .gitignore file for EE](https://gist.github.com/shoeshine/7264360).

If you find that your newly ignored files are still being tracked, try this:

`git commit -am "your commit message"` (you need to first commit current changes)
`git rm -r --cached .`
(Or if you just want to cherry pick a file: `git rm --cached path/to/file/to/ignore`)
`git add .`
`git commit -m "fixed untracked files"`

---

**12)** Add [Focus Lab's EE master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) (follow their instructions) paying special attention to set the correct *production* and local database info.

If you have a team and each developer will be working on the site with his/her own local database, it is helpful to make a copy of config.local.php (rename to EXAMPLE.config.local.php), then ignore config.local.php so the local db settings are not committed and pushed.

---

**13)** Export your live site's database and import it into your local site's database.
Do whatever other steps you may need to get your local site running properly. Sync upload directories and/or templates in EE, as needed.

You should be running an exact copy of your live site now.

---

**14)** Once you have your local site running with the Master Config, commit those changes.
`git commit -am "message describing changes for this commit"`

---

Make changes locally, commit, push (`git push origin master`). Then pull from your server via ssh connection (`git pull origin master`) when you're ready to make those changes live. Or setup an auto-deploy hook/action for your server. Any database changes you make locally will have to replicated on the live site, so make careful note of them!

Comment: If you have git running on the server, why bother with Bitbucket in the middle? Why not push directly from local?

Comment: If you have a team, you need a central hub.

Comment: Ah right, I think I get you... would it be the case that if developer-A and developer-B both commit->push the same file with conflicting changes then git wouldn't complain about that? Also, could you not have that "central" origin repo running on the server instead of at a third-party? Then use git hooks to trigger the pull from origin?

Comment: You should always `git status` and `git pull` before `git push`. You can't push a conflict. It'll be rejected. When you pull, if there's a conflict, you fix it then commit and push the fix. Yes, the central origin repo can be on any server (I used to do this), but Bitbucket does it so well for free. I prefer it now.

Comment: If I understand this process, at the end making changes live requires two steps: 1. Locally push to bitbucket (git push origin master) and 2. From the server git pull origin master. It sounds great. Hope you find the time to add steps for setting up a staging site.

Comment: Just one question regarding security. I thought making a git repo on the server was not safe. Do you use any htaccess rule to hide the "live" repo?

Comment: Sergio, I haven't tried this yet, but am planning to eliminate the extra step of pulling with this approach: http://ryanflorence.com/deploying-websites-with-a-tiny-git-hook/

Comment: @SergioAcosta, since, in my example, I'm using Bitbucket, the repo is secured behind your login. IF you were to put your central origin "hub" repo on your server without setting up a password-protected area it'd be available to anyone. My version above is secure.

Comment: I got it, so that Bitbucket step is also a safe measure in your example.

Comment: For this specific site I normally need the help of other developers, so Bitbucket makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your help, Stephen!

Comment: Is it not the case that setting up the 'hub' repo above web root and then having the public sites as 'bare' repos would avoid any security concerns? Seems to be equivalent to SVN 'working copies' combined with a standard SVN centralised repo...

Comment: @JamesSmith, yep, that'd work. :)

Comment: Wouldn't step 11 (gitignore) be in place before pulling the repo to my local machine (step 9)? Once files are cloned from Bitbucket, are they already locally tracked? Not sure this question makes sense...

Comment: @SergioAcosta, either way. If you add the .gitignore file to the prod server before doing the initial commit (before step 2), then you won't get those files when pushing/pulling. I prefer to grab them initially and then ignore them once I have them locally. There are other commands such async (or just FTP) to grab images you may want to view locally later that are ignored. My steps here are basic, but at almost every level there are more details/options/variations.

Comment: @stephen-callender, I have a specific concern regarding the staging site setup:  [link](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/15283/file-structure-for-a-staging-site-is-different-from-production) Hope you can help

Comment: @stephen-callender, I'm adding the .gitignore file to the prod server before doing the initial commit. Now, since system folder is above web root, should the .gitignore file be placed above the root directory? In that case, should I add extra rules to hide server files like perl5/ or public_ftp/ folders?

Comment: @SergioAcosta, place the .gitignore file in the same directory in the base folder of your git repo. If you have server files, like public_ftp, add them to .gitignore, just like cgi-bin in the example file linked above.