# File structure for a staging site is different from production

Tags: config, focus-lab-master-config, config-overrides, staging-server

On my current project the production site has the following folder structure:

```
--system
--config
--public_html
  -assets
  -index.php
  -admin.php
  -etc.
```

But, the staging site I need to create is different:

```
--system
--config
--public_html
  |
  |staging_subdirectory
    -index.php
    -admin.php
    -etc.
```

Both sites will have the system folder above web root and use focuslab's config setup.

Git workflow is also involved, so my best guess is to create a "staging" branch with the specific folder structure and only push to staging from that branch.

I know I can use a subdomain, but who would I set the $system_path variable located in the index.php and admin.php?  Is staging overrides the way to go?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had this same issue. I resolved this way.

I pointed my staging domain to: | staging_subdirectory / public_html

And file structure looked like this:

```
--system
--config
--public_html
  |
  |staging_subdirectory
    -system
    -config
    -public_html
        -index.php
        -admin.php
        -etc.
```

I deployed production to `/` and staging to `/public_html/staging_subdirectory/`

Comment: If I understand, the above web root -system and -config folders are empty directories in the staging server, right?

Comment: Yes, I duplicated so staging was completely independant from production