# Source control and EE: suggestions?

Tags: ee2, bestpractice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ExpressionEngine and GIT Process](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/387/expressionengine-and-git-process)

This is an odd hybrid question, so I'm not sure if I'm asking it in the right spot. If this should go somewhere else, please let me know. This is both asking for best-practice suggestions, and asking about two products: Github (for source control) and EE (for all site content.)

I've started a role with a company that's just implemented using Github for source control. Fine and dandy. We have the images, the server-side files, and some CRM integration files that we upload with FTP, and we're using Github to source-control those files. However...with EE, all the textual content is in the databases. And currently, they do daily backups of the database, but the databases are not source- or version-controlled in github. I was thinking of suggesting that the databases be backed up daily, and the database files added to Github for version control. I think that would let us "roll back" to previous versions of the entire database, but doesn't allow for granular source control of designs, content, structures, et cetera.

Do any of you have experience using source/version control with your EE-driven sites? What method or system did you use?

Comment: Hey Leigh - check out the older question which covers this same ground, lots of great answers there.

Comment: Stellar - thanks. I only just found this EE site this morning, and while I'd searched the main SO site I hadn't searched this one. (But really, I do have a brain.) Sorry!

Comment: No apologies necessary!